# PHP Imagick setImageCompression

Tags: php, imagick, image-compression

I'm just starting to write some PHP using the Imagick / ImageMagick library, and have seen several examples regarding setImageCompression which appear to implement things differently.

For example I've seen it used like this:

```
$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
```

and also like this:

```
$image->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED);
```

So, what is the relevance of the backslash before declaring the compression type? Is this specific to the compression type? A typo in examples I've seen or something else?

Comment: May be it is something about namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is only necessary when using [namespaces](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

For instance, the former won't work in `namespace Foo` because it will look for a class `Foo\Imagick`:

```
namespace {
    var_dump(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW); // int(11)
}

namespace Foo {
    var_dump(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW); // Class 'Foo\Imagick' not found
}
```

The second will work in all cases:

```
namespace {
    var_dump(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW); // int(11)
}

namespace Foo {
    var_dump(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW); // int(11)
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, the 2nd -with the backslash is better practice since it will work with or without namespaces?

Comment: Arguably yes, but also maybe overkill if you have no intention of using namespaces for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, but is a single backslash really overkill? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Only in the strictest sense, in that it's not necessary to do so; it's up to you :-)